# meteorjs Template helper Issue

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I'm new to meteor so if this is a duplication of another topic. Apologies Still getting used to terminology.

I'm unable to pull in some information from my client side javascript, to my template I don't know if this is because I have set up the name space incorrectly.

main.html

```
    <head>
      <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      {{> navigation}}
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
              {{> product_options}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
              {{> products}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       {{> footer}}
     </body>
```

products.html

```
<template name="products">
  {{#each products}}
    {{> product}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

product.html

```
<template name="product">
  {{> text}}
</template>
```

products.js

```
Template.products.helpers({
    products: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
```

I've also removed these from my project

```
autopublish  
insecure
```

I'm not sure if this is stopping me from what I am trying to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in product.html.  In spacebars you only use `>` to denote templates.  If you change your product.html to what is below it should work.  You reference properties directly in spacebars, not with `>`

```
<template name="product">
  {{text}}
</template>
```

Comment: Right, I haven't read carefully enough, Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg no problem, thanks for helping anyways :)